# Where does a custom CAS policy for ASP.NET have to go?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, code-access-security, trust

In my hosting environment I do not have access to anything outside of my virtual directory-- I can't edit the machine.config, nor the machine level web.config, nor can I put anything in the GAC.

I reading up on Medium Trust. If I want, say, Medium Trust + one additional permission, can I create a custom trust level and put it in my virtual directory, or does this require an administrator's cooperation to manually edit machine wide config files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand your virtual directory web config should be able to override the settings inherited from the machine.config file so you could create your custom trust policy within your web.config and have that enable the use of IO permissions.

Trust Settings. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648344.aspx

Config Heirarchy 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx

Comment: Ah it worked! I was able to copy the medium trust file to my virtual directory, reference it from web.config and then add or remove permissions and verify that they did indeed become available or became no longer available.